# Retrieve data from tables having many-to-many relationships?

Tags: php, mysql

[image: table 1]

[image: table 2]

[image: table 3]

Now how i select the project_title from table2 having tm_id=10

and what is the best way to do this task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT t2.project_title FROM table2 AS t2
JOIN table3 AS t3 ON t3.project_id = t2.project_id
WHERE t3.tm_id = 10;
```

Comment: Cool. Simplest is best I find. You didn't specify any other criteria so I didn't go with `INNER JOIN` or `LEFT JOIN` or `RIGHT OUTER INNER CROSS-POLINATION JOIN`. But you should read the link that @JW 웃 posted. It's a good start to using `JOIN`.

Answer (score 1):

I think a simple `INNER JOIN` will suffice your need.

```
SELECT  a.*, c.project_title
FROM    Online_team a
        INNER JOIN team_project b
            ON a.tm_id = b.tm_id
        INNER JOIN online_team_projects c   
            ON b.project_ID = c.project_ID
WHERE   a.tm_id = 10
```

To further gain more knowledge about joins, kindly visit the link below:

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

But if you don't need any columns from `Online_team`, you can remove it from the joins list.

```
SELECT  c.project_title
FROM    team_project b
        INNER JOIN online_team_projects c   
            ON b.project_ID = c.project_ID
WHERE   b.tm_id = 10
```

Answer (score 1):

use the query as below

```
 SELECT table2.project_title  from table2,table3 where table2.project_id = table3.project_id and table3.tm_id = 10
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  otp.project_title
FROM online_team_projects otp,
  team_project tp
WHERE otp.project_id = tp.project_id
    AND tp.tm_id = 10
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use this approach:

```
SELECT otp.project_title
FROM online_team ot
INNER JOIN online_team_projects otp USING (project_id)
WHERE ot.tm_id = 10
```